# Setting up router plus WiFi access point (same SSID) - roaming problems

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

Network:

```
Internet <-> Router 1 (DHCP, WiFi) <-> PowerPlug <-> Router 2 in access point mode
```

Both WiFi networks are configured with the same SSID.

If a device (i.e. laptop or phone) connects first to the WiFi in the access point everything works. If the device moves to the range of the router 1 WiFi, it roams as it should and continues to work.

However, once it has connected to the router 1 WiFi the device cannot connect back the Access Point network. If I then reset the router (not touching the AP) the device connects back.

I can only assume there is something sticky in the first router but I cannot figure out what. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

It will not leave a network unless the signal become bad enough, then it will connect to the access Point, and sticks there until its signal becomes bad enough.
When you reset (or plug out) the router, the device will connect back to the access Point because it lost the router. When the router comes back, it will not leave the access Point network unless the access Point signal becomes weak enough.

You could try reducing the transmit Power of the router and/or access point so the overlapping of router and access Point is not too large. This can usually be done in settings.

The reason it "sticks" to the router is because the router has a stronger signal over a larger area. If you want to play around a Little, try moving out of range of the router.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't explain the behavior. The routers are really far apart (40m, 5 rooms in between), the signal of router 1 is barely visible in the other side. On top of that, the same behavior appears when using a different SSID for the AP.

Comment: yes both are true. The signal must basically completely disappear Before the computer will try to connect to a Another network. You could try reducing the transmit Power of the router and/or AP to lets say 90% to make sure the signal completely disappears for it to connect to the stronger device. You would have to experment around a bit to get good settings that work in a "roaming" fashion without losing the Connection in-between.